# is an ajax call after rendering an mvc view duplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I'm going to be developing a new system and am toying with the idea of either creating a single page application or a full asp.net mvc website.

I want to utilise knockout so if I went down the mvc route i'd need to load my mvc view and on document ready then make the ajax call to bind to my knockout view model.

Is this a bad approach as i'm effectively making 2 calls to get one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends really on your exact page design and behavior.
But generally MVC and knockout do not require you to get the data via ajax, you can populate your data from the server then manually apply bindings to your observables.

saving the data could be done via ajax.

Of course its all theory now, you need to see your screen designs and check which way to go.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean about not having to populate your data via ajax? How else would you get the json into a model? Apologies if thats a really stupid question!!

Comment: Its not a stupid question at all and is valid most of the time.
What i meant is that you can actually populate your html from the server using classic MVC functionality. but adding your "data-bind" attributes to your inputs. that works well when you have a form with inputs.
I'm kinda busy but maybe later i can post some sample code.

Comment: I answered a similar question with details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480138/mixed-knockout-and-server-side-rendering/17364310#17364310
i think it will help you.